# Android_Prompt not showing in Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, prompt

I tried setting prompt text in Java and Xml, but neither shows prompt text. 
I tried spinner.getPrompt and it shows the text but when i debug, in Spinner object mPromptValue is null.

Any ideas? 
SO here is my xml

```
     <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/brojracuna"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:prompt="@string/prompt_lista"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView" >
        </Spinner>
```

where is string.xml

```
<string name="prompt_lista">10</string>
```

and in my Java code

```
final Spinner prikazRacuna = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.brojracuna);
prikazRacuna.setPrompt("10");
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("10", "20", "30"));
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
            (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    prikazRacuna.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Some code would be nice

Comment: There, sorry for not posting before

Comment: which version of android you are using?